# Extracting XY coordinates from Gcode using c++ regex parser

Tags: c++, windows

I am trying to parse through a gcode file and need to extract the XY coordinates from the uploaded gcode.
I tried to parse but after running my code only the X-coordinate is printing not XY coordinates.

Also, how can I add a stop in the parser when it encounters a G92 in the line.
I want it to parse when line has G1 and stop when it encounters a G92.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream gcode ("circuit.gcode");
    string line;
    regex coord_regex("[XY].?\\d+.\\d+");
    smatch coord_match;
    while (getline(gcode, line))
    {
        if (regex_search(line, coord_match, coord_regex))
        {
            cout << coord_match[0]<< " - "<< coord_match[1]<< endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Image

[Gcode input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEJ1x.png)

[Current Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUy1h.png)

Comment: `if (line.find("G92") != std::string::npos) break;` ought to be enough to satisfy the stop-requirement.

Comment: Thanks, that helped with the stop command @JeremyFriesner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured it out instead of searching for Y in the line I took X as a start and parsed the whole string altogether.

This is the final code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream gcode (test1.gcode");
    string line;
    regex coord_regex("[X].?\\d+.\\d+.\\s.\\w+.\\d+\\d+");
    smatch coord_match;
    while (getline(gcode, line))
    {
        if (regex_search(line, coord_match, coord_regex))
        {   
            if (line.find("G1") != std::string::npos) 
            {
                cout << coord_match[0]<< endl;
               
            }
            else if (line.find("G92") != std::string::npos){ 
            
                break;
            }
        }
    }    
    return 0;
}
```